# IIS 6.1 Handlers for HTML, ASP, INC files

Tags: html, asp-classic, include, iis-6, handlers

I have a legacy website in which .HTML, .ASP, and .INC files are being used. Problem is all pages have VBScript code not parsed by IIS and thus written on page as static text. I want to fix it. All .html pages include both .ASP and .INC for scripts.

Now currently IIS Handlers are as below: all .htm, .html, .inc have IsapiModule handlers as well as ServerSideIncludeModule. This is what I suspect causing issue. So now if I remove ServerSideIncludeModule handlers and just keep IsapiModule, it parses VBScritpt correctly but HTML pages with INC inclusion do not open but ask to save a file to download. What am I missing here? This worked on my localhost fine but not on Production.

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: I tried removing all SSImodules for .htm/.html and didnt work. I tried removing both handlers for .inc and didnt work that way too.

Comment: if it's IIS 6.1 check if ASP Scripting module is anebled on server ... don't remember the exact location of this config but is in IIS administrator

Comment: you mean IsapiModule? Its path would be '%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll' and as I mentioned already, IsapiModule is already there and that's what being used for current htm/html/inc parsing. Let me know if this is what you meant. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this problem and posting solution so that someone reading this later can try this if it helps..

we did "Set enable 32-bit Applications to False" in Application Pool for this website and it resolved the issue. No handlers were changed while doing this.

Comment: this is work for me.but In case of .net com dll we required enable 32-bit to true to run work this dll.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue on client and server side code. HTML pages can read only client side code but not the server side code. Asp is a server side language and a server can read asp codes written on a .asp extension file.
So my suggestion will be try your codes in .asp files. Browsers will read the HTML codes and show you the HTML output and IIS will read the server side codes(vb-script codes)

Comment: I know bys using right handlers HTML page can behave as ASP page. so sure it is Handlers issue in IIS which I am not able to solve. Converting to ASP is not an option as of now.

Comment: I can understand. I've just suggested that one. There may be many more better suggestions of your own. You can try it with just one or two pages. Debugging is one of the daily routines of programmers